# How can deploy signed APK when click Run in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, signed-apk

I am developing an app which uses Google APIs. I have created credentials at "Google Developers Console". If I creates a signed APK, and run it on the phone, there is no problem.

The problem is, while I developing the app, when I click RUN button, it deploys an unsigned version of the app on the phone. Thus the application does not work.

How can I set Android Studio to make it deploy signed APK on the phone  when click RUN button?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Add these values to your .gradle:

```
signingConfigs{
    debug{
        keyAlias 'your key alias'
        keyPassword 'your keypassword'
        storeFile file('keystore path')
        storePassword 'your storepassword'
    }
}
buildTypes {
    debug{
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
}
```

The keystore path in the file will be something like `E:/xxx/xxx/xx.keystore`.

Comment: I always get this error: "Installation failed with message Failed to finalize session : INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: /data/app/vmdl52362262.tmp/1_slice__ signatures are inconsistent.
It is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling an existing version of the apk if it is present, and then re-installing." i uninstalled menually but your code not work for me why?

Comment: i solved my "signatures are inconsistent" error with this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42703302/1472483

Comment: Which level? `Project` or `Module`

Comment: @SD826E I put this config in the Module level, something called 'app'

Answer (score 20):

Usually I do it from command line, installing via "adb install -r file.apk" (-r to preserve app's data)

Also it can be done via Gradle and project settings, see answers here: [Android Studio - Run signed apk on emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24895267/android-studio-run-signed-apk-on-emulator)

Comment: this is the correct way: Generate signed Apk then install it with this command "adb install -r path_to/app-release.apk". Previous answer (modifying signingConfigs{}) will not generate a proper release version of the app like that you launch to the Google Play.

Answer (score 1):

When I want to test my APK release I just use ADB-Link. Its free and very easy to setup. Just make sure to delete any previous builds that you installed on your device otherwise the installation will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is not an answer to your question about how to sign the app before running it, but have you thought about the option to create a new signature key for the debug key you are using? You could use a separate API key in debug mode.

I found some extra information about using a key in release and debug mode:
[Android: automatically choose debug/release Maps v2 api key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17141008/android-automatically-choose-debug-release-maps-v2-api-key)