# Slice signatures are inconsistent with android studio default run

Tags: android, gradle, build, split, android-studio-2.3

I've configured gradle for signing with:

```
android {
    ...
    signingConfigs{
        debug {
            storeFile file("...");
            storePassword '...'
            keyAlias '...'
            keyPassword '...'
        }
    }
}
```

Now when I run the Gradle task installDebug the app is signed and installed correctly and I can run the app as expected. But when I run the app module (android studio default run, which is much preferred for debugging). I get the message:

```
Failed to finalize session : INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK:
/data/app/vmdl2083307194.tmp/1_slice__ signatures are inconsistent
```

This happens even when No apk is yet installed.

I think it has to do with android studio splitting the apk improperly. So if nobody knows how to make it sign correctly a way to keep android studio from splitting the apk will probably also work.

Answer (score 50):

I just ran into the exact problem after defining the signature for the debug build. After deleting the previous app from the test device, **Clean Project** / **Rebuild Project** did the trick for me.

Comment: I tried that very often (as I usually do with any build problem) but the problem seems to have solved itself after an android studio update