# In App Update API always returns 1 (UPDATE_NOT_AVAILABLE)

Tags: android, android-app-bundle, in-app-update

I am using `In-App Update API` in the application for Update Application while the new version is available in play store.

**module gradle**

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxx.xxxxx"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode rootProject.ext.vCode
        versionName rootProject.ext.vName
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
```

**Last upload version(Live in Playstore)**

```
vCode = 5
vName = "1.0.4"
```

**project gradle (downgrade it for the testing)**

```
vCode = 4
vName = "1.0.3"
```

Downgrade this version for the testing update available or not.

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var appUpdateManager: AppUpdateManager? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        appUpdateManager = AppUpdateManagerFactory.create(this)
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
            checkForVersionUpdate()
    }


    private fun checkForVersionUpdate() {
            appUpdateManager?.appUpdateInfo?.addOnSuccessListener { appUpdateInfo ->
                if ((appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.DEVELOPER_TRIGGERED_UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS)) {
                    // If an in-app update is already running, resume the update.
                    startUpdateFlow(appUpdateInfo)
                } else if (appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.UPDATE_AVAILABLE
                        && appUpdateInfo.isUpdateTypeAllowed(IMMEDIATE)) {
                    startUpdateFlow(appUpdateInfo)
                }
            }
    }

    private fun startUpdateFlow(appUpdateInfo: AppUpdateInfo) {
        try {
            appUpdateManager?.startUpdateFlowForResult(
                    appUpdateInfo,
                    IMMEDIATE,
                    this,
                    123)
        } catch (e: InvocationTargetException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        } catch (e: IntentSender.SendIntentException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        if (requestCode == 123) {
            if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
                Log.i("Update failed code:", resultCode.toString())
                // If the update is cancelled or fails,
                // you can request to start the update again.
            } else if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED)
                checkForVersionUpdate()
        }
    }
}
```

**I last uploaded build in play store with App Bundle(.aab) and Open Beta.**

**Tried following ways.**

- Sign apk with the same package name.
- Clear Playstore apk cache and storage.
- Download apk from playstore and uninstall it from device. then after downgrade version code and sign apk and install it in device. Still not showing update app dialog.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Were you able to sort it out?

Comment: For me, using an emulator was the issue. Worked fine on physical device.

Comment: Thanks, clearing the cache and storage did the trick for me

Comment: @bahaeddinsagar I didn't believe it would but clearing the `storage` fixed it for me. I just kept clearing the cache and that didn't have any effect. Thanks!

Comment: i try to clearing the cache storage from play store. but, it can't work

Answer (score 8):

Contrary to other answers that say that test build must be in release mode or has to be uploaded to Play Console Test track - that is all wrong, nowhere in the documentation there is any mention of any of that.

If you meet requirements API >= 21 && have internet connection and face this issue, do the following to resolve:

- Confirm that your test build has lower version code than what's in production
- Clear Storage & Cache for PlayStore app
- Open play store using account that has previously downloaded the app
- Navigate to your app listing in PlayStore and confirm that "Update" button is showing.

It seems like a caching issue with PlayStore and above steps refresh it. After that you'll be able to test In App Updates even in debug mode.

Comment: It should be signed with the same key, see [docs here](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/in-app-updates#troubleshoot)

Comment: But you're right, you can skip uploading to Google Play, just use the APK with lesser version code.

Comment: I installed the signed APK and play store shows me the update button even I received update status is UPDATE_NOT_AVAILABLE=.

Comment: @PravinDharam same here. Were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 4):

What is helping me during testing is opening Google play store app and open "My apps & games" position from drawer menu.

Make sure on "Updates" tab your tested application appears in "Updates Pending".

That library in my opinion does not check on some google api is there any update available, but is checking some kind of google play store app cache

hope it helps
cheers
Wojtek

Comment: It seems like it works exactly as you described.

Comment: in my case this is telling me that there is an update but still the app does not detect the update. no idea why. ps i made sure to install the app from playstore

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I test my in-app update and it's confirmed working for me everytime I rollout.

I use internal test track and increment version code.

1. use Google play store to install a version of the testing app (I used internal test track rollout)
2. rollout another version with higher VERSION CODE on Play Console (the same internal test track)
3. close both testing app and Google play store (not just back to home, use recent key and swipe them off)
4. open the Google play store and ensure that testing app has an update available (you can check it under "My Apps & Game" > Installed)
5. now open the testing app and check for UPDATE_AVAILABLE

This works for me almost immediately after rollout

[Android In-App Update Api showing UPDATE_NOT_AVAILABLE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57835987/4253741)

Answer (score 2):

I also faced same issue and none of the above solutions not worked. What I understand is if the `versionCode` is incremented in build.gradle, then it will identify as an update.

I followed below sequence.

- Asume your current `versionCode` in `build.gradle` is `10` and `versionName` is `1.10` and your app supports in-app updates(required code to check for the update)
- Build the debug apk
- Upload it to https://play.google.com/console/internal-app-sharing
- Install the app in the test device with the help of app download link
- Open the app at least once in test device
- Now change `versionCode` to `11` and `versionName` to `1.11` in app `build.gradle`
- Build debug app, upload it to the internal-app-sharing and get the app download link
- In your test device open the second dowload link at least once(Just open - do not click on the Update button)
- Now open the app the app, It will show App update dialog.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure:

1. you install Signed Release version for testing
2. with the same applicationId as in Play Store (your flavour doesn't have any applicationIdSuffix)
3. and versionCode is lower
4. and your app is released (as a tester you can download it)

Comment: Signed release is not necessary, pl. refer to one of the other answers here.

Answer (score 1):

For me the issue was that I was logged in to play store from multiple google accounts. when tried on a phone with only 1 gmail account , it worked