# android AppUpdateInfo.updateAvailability always return 1

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-update, google-play-core

```
private fun checkRecentVersion() {
    val appUpdateManager = AppUpdateManagerFactory.create(this)
    val appUpdateInfoTask = appUpdateManager.appUpdateInfo

    appUpdateInfoTask.addOnSuccessListener { appUpdateInfo ->
        if (appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.UPDATE_AVAILABLE) {
            setView(false, updateAvailability = appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability())
        } else {
            setView(true, updateAvailability = appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability())
        }
    }.addOnFailureListener {
        setView(true, true, -100)
    }
}
```

I check this code update my app upload in internal test.
I want to update check use appUpdateManager.
But it was return always 1(UPDATE_NOT_AVAILABLE).
What is the problem this code?
And if I use update internal test update, it can't usable this code?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, nothing worked until I cleared the cach and data for playstore app.
as mentioned in Mehul Kabaria answer in the below thread

[In App Update API always returns 1 (UPDATE_NOT_AVAILABLE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56863431/in-app-update-api-always-returns-1-update-not-available)