# Best practice to debug Android In-App Update

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, in-app-update

I tried to use Google In-App Updates library in my application that already in the Playstore. But i have some problems about how to test it. I am not gonna use FakeAppUpdateManager since there are no UI is being shown and no update is really performed

**First**, I cannot test it with debug build even if i set the versionCode lower than Playstore version code because of different keystore.

**Second**, According some tutorials said that i must using release build and signed with same keystore that i use to upload on Playstore. but when i did that, i still didn't get any in-app update. My guess is: because i used Google App Signing so the fingerprint is different and it is not recognized as same application (let me know if i am wrong about this).

Is there any elegant way to test this out?

Comment: Check this working solution, which I have answered this StackOverflow question : https://stackoverflow.com/a/65321834/6463877