# Verify Trusted Web Activity to hide address bar in the App

Tags: android, url, google-play, progressive-web-apps, trusted-web-activity

I'm trying to publish my PWA  Google Play but I can't get it hide address bar in Chrome when the app is open.

It seems that a file needs to be added to the server and I do it

https://crux.commonms.com/ppo/.well-known/assetlinks.json

with the information given by this application:

https://developers.google.com/digital-asset-links/tools/generator

but when I try to fill it with my data:

```
crux.commonms.com/ppo
com.commonms.patientportal
09: E9: C6: BE: B2: 8F: A2: C8: 97: 18: 9E: 7C: 28: A4: 8D: AE: 6F: DA: 68: 7E: CA: 9C: F7: 0A: BD: C7: B1: FA: E1: 97: EC: 9F
```

When I click on `'Test Statment'` I have an 'Invalid input field (s)' error, it may be because I have the application in a folder inside the server ('ppo'), but it is there.

I looking for a solution and there was another question

[TWA - Digital Asset Link OK but address bar still visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56489790/twa-digital-asset-link-ok-but-address-bar-still-visible)

to which they recommend this application

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dev.conn.assetlinkstool&hl=en

and i have tried too but the adress bar is still visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `assetlinks.json` file needs to be at `.well-known/assetlinks.json`, relative to the root of the domain. You seem to have the file under a `/ppo` folder, which is the wrong location. Moving the file to following location should solve the problem.:

`https://crux.commonms.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json`