# Cannot install debug and release version on same device

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-build-type

I have configured build variants in my project with `applicationIdSuffix` so that I can install both debug and release versions on my device.
here is my `build.gradle` (relevant parts):

```
 buildTypes {
        debug {
            buildConfigField "String", "BASE_URL", '"http://dev.xyz.com"'

            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
        }
        release {
            buildConfigField "String", "BASE_URL", '"http://api.xyz.com"'
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

But when I try to install both, it fails. I tried different ways:

**1.** Generated both debug and release apks and transferred them to my phone storage. The first one installs, and the second one gives an error **"App not installed"** - no further info. This is the same no matter which version I install first.

**2.** Installed debug version from storage, then tried to install release version from play store, but play store gives error :

> cant install app error code:-505.

**3.** Installed release version from store, and then tried running the project from android studio, and this is my 'run' log :

```
    Launching app
    $ adb push D:\myPROJECTS\MyApp\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk /data/local/tmp/com.example.myapp.debug
    $ adb shell pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.example.myapp.debug"
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for java.lang.String android.os.SystemProperties.native_get(java.lang.String) (tried Java_android_os_SystemProperties_native_1get and Java_android_os_SystemProperties_native_1get__Ljava_lang_String_2)
      at android.os.SystemProperties.native_get(Native Method)
      at android.os.SystemProperties.get(SystemProperties.java:52)
      at android.os.Environment$UserEnvironment.<init>(Environment.java:123)
      at android.os.Environment.initForCurrentUser(Environment.java:98)
      at android.os.Environment.<clinit>(Environment.java:92)
      at android.os.Environment.getLegacyExternalStorageDirectory(Environment.java:597)
      at android.os.Debug.<clinit>(Debug.java:103)
      at android.ddm.DdmHandleHello.handleHELO(DdmHandleHello.java:164)
      at android.ddm.DdmHandleHello.handleChunk(DdmHandleHello.java:91)
      at org.apache.harmony.dalvik.ddmc.DdmServer.dispatch(DdmServer.java:171)
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: android.os.Debug
      at android.ddm.DdmHandleHello.handleFEAT(DdmHandleHello.java:176)
      at android.ddm.DdmHandleHello.handleChunk(DdmHandleHello.java:93)
      at org.apache.harmony.dalvik.ddmc.DdmServer.dispatch(DdmServer.java:171)
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: android.os.Debug
      at android.ddm.DdmHandleProfiling.handleMPRQ(DdmHandleProfiling.java:187)
      at android.ddm.DdmHandleProfiling.handleChunk(DdmHandleProfiling.java:88)
      at org.apache.harmony.dalvik.ddmc.DdmServer.dispatch(DdmServer.java:171)
    Aborted 

    $ adb shell am start -n "com.example.myapp.debug/com.example.myapp.LoginActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
    Error while executing: am start -n "com.example.myapp.debug/com.example.myapp.LoginActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
    Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.myapp.debug/com.example.myapp.LoginActivity }
    Error type 3
    Error: Activity class {com.example.myapp.debug/com.example.myapp.LoginActivity} does not exist.

    Error while Launching activity
```

any idea what is going on?

**Update** : don't know if it helps, but here is how I declared my launcher activity in `androidmanifest.xml` :

```
<activity
    android:name=".LoginActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Launcher">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Have you tried to change the name of your `android:name=".AppClassDebug"` and launcher activity to `MainActivityDebug`? I see that you add suffix to the package name, which is fine.

Comment: Sorry I dont follow. Do you mean change the name of my launcher activity class? How would that help?

Comment: I think your appSuffix is interesting in the gradle but if you're using build variants why not just use a manifest.xml with a different application name? that way when you build you know pm isn't going to get confused.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, I figured out what was going on.

I was actually creating an unsigned apk for the debug variant (**Build > Build APK**). But I had to use (**Build > Generate Signed APK**) and then select the debug variant from the options.

[image]

Also, when running the project on my device, gradle would be generating an unsigned apk. So that too wouldn't work. That is - unless I configure `SigningConfigs` as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24896329/3894781).

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using build types, why not use product Flavors instead? Here's a link to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html) on how to do this, as well as what you are currently trying to do. Hope this helps.

Comment: not exactly an answer but considering nobody else responded, bounty's all yours.

Comment: @ShahiM Yes, I realized that after you had posted your solution, but thank you!

Comment: Is there any way to automatically change package_name in the google-services.json file as well?